# 802.11 Channel Use Regs

Tags: wifi, fcc, 802.11

With a 5.8 Ghz WLAN device, operating in the upper UNIII band of 5745-5825 MHz...

Is it required that, if the device is using a standard 20 MHz-wide 802.11 channel, that you can only be centered on the pre-defined frequencies of ch149 (5745 MHz), ch153 (5765 MHz), ch157 (5785 MHz), ch161 (5805 MHz) or ISM Band ch165 (5825 MHz)?

Is it not allowed to set the center of the 20 MHz-wide operation channel to, say, ch155 (5775 MHz)?

I would think that as long as you are within the 5745-5825 MHz band, it shouldn't matter what the center frequency is.

I'm being told that with a 20 MHz device, you can only use those 5 pre-defined channels as their center frequency. What about devices capable of 10 MHz and 5 MHz wide channel use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If your equipment supports it, you can set it to Channel 155, however, this is not desirable, as you will get interference from the two adjacent channels. The recommendations are just that, recommendations. There are no requirements in FCC 15.245 or 15.247 (ISM regulations) for a specific channel, as long as you are not near the band's edge.

Edit: 
Following Dave's comment: There are the U-NII (15.407) rules which differ slightly from the 15.247 rules, but there is no specific channel requirements. If the equipment supports it, any frequency inside the band can be used. 
As for narrow band FHSS transmissions, there is a different set of requirements which applies to them.

Comment: He can use only 20 Mhz of the 80 MHz channel if he wants to. Also, FCC 15.401. There are more documents to read for the 5.8GHz ISM band

Answer (score 0):

The other answer has addressed the possibility from the *regulatory* point of view, where the FCC in the US, and other such regulatory organizations in other countries, might impose certain requirements on what is allowable for communications in unlicensed bands like the 5.8 GHz bands. In theory, then, there is no regulation of usage to just those 5 pre-defined channels, for 802.11 devices.

But since the question is talking about the use of the 5.8 GHz band usage by 802.11 devices, one needs to consider the IEEE 802.11 standards as well as the Wi-Fi Alliance's certifications. Based solely on what the regulatory agencies allowed in the 5.8 GHz band, the 802.11 standards and Wi-Fi Alliance's corresponding certifications *could* have defined more channels. However, given that the channel sizes are 20 MHz (and later, also 40 MHz, 80 MHz, and most recently, even 160 MHz), and the 5.8 GHz band size is fixed, more channels would mean more overlap in channels, as well as more system and RF complexity to handle more possible center frequencies, more signaling overhead, etc., without significant benefits. Hence, they chose only some of the possible center frequencies.

Having said that, the number of channels is more than 5. A table of the available channels can be found at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels), for example.

As for the question, "What about devices that are capable of 10mhz and 5mhz wide channel use?", this is not relevant for 802.11-based WLAN devices, as they don't use 10 MHz or 5 MHz channels.